# Regular expression index value with word boundary

Tags: c#, .net, regex

The following is returning `0`; is there any way I can get at the value of `4`?

```
var searchString = "two";
var result = Regex.Match("one two", "\b" + searchString + "\b").Index
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: varbatim string `Regex.Match("one two", @"\btwo\b").Index`

Comment: varbatim string `Regex.Match("one two", @"\btwo\b").Index`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use verbatim strings:

```
Regex.Match("one two", @"\b" + searchString + @"\b").Index
                       ^                      ^
```

In your code, the `\b` is interpreted as a backspace character. Prefixing a string literal with `@` makes the compiler ignore string escape sequences and pass the `\b` as-is to the regex engine.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
Regex.Match("one two", "\\btwo\\b").Index
```

I cannot use a verbatim string because in my work example the string "two" is a variable. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If `two` is a variable you can use `@"\b" + pattern + @"\b"` but that's doesn't change readability very much.